# Fluent Ribbon not compiling in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, fluent-ribbon

I'm relatively new to Visual Studio and I'm trying to compile the Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase from this repository: https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon

I've installed .NET core SDK v3.1.300, but I'm still getting many errors when I try to compile.

[image: Screenshot of errors]

Build Log:

```
NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
1>------ Build started: Project: Fluent.Ribbon, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>'""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>operable program or batch file.
1>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon\Fluent.Ribbon.csproj(64,5): error MSB3073: The command """" exited with code 9009.
1>Done building project "Fluent.Ribbon.csproj" -- FAILED.
2>------ Build started: Project: Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency JetBrains.Annotations does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency MahApps.Metro does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.Material does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency StyleCop.Analyzers does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency WpfAnalyzers does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1602: Fluent.Ribbon does not provide an inclusive lower bound for dependency ControlzEx. An approximate best match of ControlzEx 2.0.0.54 was resolved.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency JetBrains.Annotations does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency MahApps.Metro does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.Material does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency StyleCop.Analyzers does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency WpfAnalyzers does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1602: Fluent.Ribbon does not provide an inclusive lower bound for dependency ControlzEx. An approximate best match of ControlzEx 2.0.0.54 was resolved.
2>Done building project "Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj" -- FAILED.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency JetBrains.Annotations does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency MahApps.Metro does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.Material does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency StyleCop.Analyzers does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1604: Project dependency WpfAnalyzers does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
2>C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon-develop\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase\Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj : error NU1602: Fluent.Ribbon does not provide an inclusive lower bound for dependency ControlzEx. An approximate best match of ControlzEx 2.0.0.54 was resolved.
2>Done building project "Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the .csproject content for Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase. It's unchanged from what I downloaded off of GitHub:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>FluentTest</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase</AssemblyName>
    
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);SA0001</NoWarn>
    <InlcudeMahAppsMetro>true</InlcudeMahAppsMetro>
    <InlcudeMahAppsMetro Condition="$(TargetFramework) == 'net452'">false</InlcudeMahAppsMetro>

    <DefineConstants Condition="$(InlcudeMahAppsMetro)">$(DefineConstants);MahApps_Metro</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject>FluentTest.Program</StartupObject>
    <ApplicationIcon>Icons\App.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.manifest" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="$(InlcudeMahAppsMetro) == false">
    <Page Remove="MahMetro*" />
    <Compile Remove="MahMetro*" />
    <None Include="MahMetro*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Fluent.Ribbon\Fluent.Ribbon.csproj" />

    <PackageReference Include="MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.Material" />
    <PackageReference Include="MahApps.Metro" Condition="$(InlcudeMahAppsMetro)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains(NETCOREAPP)) == false">
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsFormsIntegration" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Please post the full build log as text, there's likely something missing that needs to be installed, but it's not in the screenshot.

Comment: Okay, give me a second and I'll edit the question

Comment: Added the build log, is this what you need? Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks a lot

Comment: I've gone through and installed the listed dependencies through NuGet, bit it has made no change to the build log output.

Comment: Your .csproj file content will also help.

Comment: Added the .csproject content for Fluent.Ribbon.Showcase

Comment: OK, this is an old question, but I can hardly believe there's something called `InlcudeMahAppsMetro`, it should rightly be `IncludeMahAppsMetro`.